# Enable text area by clicking a button and not printing it at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

So I came across this problem and cant come up with a solution with vanilla js which I most prefer to use (no jQuery).

I have a textarea which is disabled at first and can get enabled with a button push (let's say button i). So when I push the button 'i' it enables the textarea BUT it also prints it out, which I don't want to happen.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode == 73) {
        document.getElementById('focus').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('focus').focus();
    } 
});
```

So basically my question is how to enable it on one button push and not print it, but print it after it has been enabled, (e.g second push) preventDefault() is nice, but not for this task, because it prevents the character from printing at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "prints it out"? Also, if you could post a working snippet that would be better.

Comment: A simple hack would be to just clear the text box after the letter is pressed.

Comment: Please add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that highlights the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the letter from appearing in the text area. However, you'll have to neutralize the event listener afterwards, if you want the user to be able to type the letter i.

```js
const focus = document.getElementById('focus');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function eventListener(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 73) {
    return;
  }
  
  focus.disabled = false;
  focus.focus();

  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior

  document.removeEventListener('keydown', eventListener); // remove the event listener
});
```

```html
<textarea id="focus" disabled></textarea>
```